# values keep piling append function python

Tags: python, list

i have a list `li_LBF` which has 287 list inside it..i want calculate the Euclidean Distance between every list..but my code not working...the list where i am trying to store the output `li_LBF_1` keeps getting bigger every time i run the code ..first time it was 287..2nd time i ran it it became 2x287..and keeps getting bigger..

```
li1=[]
li_LBF=[[1257.0, 1004.0, 284.0, 135.0, 100.0, 54.0, 47.0, 38.0, 56.0, 75.0, 104.0, 147.0, 154.0, 316.0, 101.0, 203.0, 87.0, 153.0, 88.0, 97.0, 97.0, 153.0, 339.0, 825.0, 1430.0, 11856.0], [1249.0, 998.0, 291.0, 140.0, 103.0, 60.0, 43.0, 39.0, 61.0, 82.0, 112.0, 154.0, 160.0, 312.0, 108.0, 209.0, 90.0, 149.0, 89.0, 100.0, 94.0, 162.0, 327.0, 831.0, 1410.0, 11827.0],........]]
def LBF_conversion(li_LBF):
    for i in range(len(li_LBF)):
      if i==0:
        list2=li_LBF[i]
        i+=1
      else:
        list1=list2
        list2=li_LBF[i]
        dist = euclidean(list1, list2)
        li_LBF_1.append(dist)
        
    return li_LBF_1
li1=LBF_conversion(li_LBF)
print(li1)
```

Comment: Please fix the example code in your question, it cannot run as is.

Comment: The problem probably comes from not understanding that the assignment operator for lists doesn't create a *copy*, it creates a *reference*. To copy, you should do `a = list(b)`. Or, as I prefer, `import copy; a = copy.copy(b)`. Until you fix your code I cannot know for certain.

Comment: @GaiusJulius dont know what is wrong with my code....al i want to do is not keep piling up previous values..

Comment: You should try to create a minimum working example that recreates your problem. This is a piece of code that runs independently of the rest of your code. Here, for example, you are passing `li_LBF` to the function `LBF_conversion` without ever creating it.

Comment: @GaiusJulius no i have li_LBF .it exists..i take it from another output

Comment: You have it. We don't, so we cannot test your code. Also we don't know who `li_LBF_1` is, it is not created. Anyway, my feeling is that you are missing that assignment operators in Python create references (pointers) to lists and not copies. So `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a; b.append(4)` will also edit the original list `a`. But doing `b = list(a)` or `b=copy.copy(a)` will not cause this problem, because it copies the **values** and not the **pointer**.

Comment: @GaiusJulius now i edited it properly..please help

Comment: @GaiusJulius Why do you prefer `copy.copy(b)` over `b.copy()`?

Comment: `i += 1` has no effect. The next iteration will get the new value of `i` from the `range` object, not by incrementing `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not initializing `li_LBF_1`. So you're referencing the global variable, which retains the value from the previous call, and you add more elements to it.

Put `li_LBF_1 = []` at the beginning of the function.